mlr3: Error Accessing Model Coefficients in lrn("surv.penalized")
I encountered an error when trying to access model coefficients using mlr3. Can you help me understand how to do this properly?
library(haven)
library(tidyverse)
library(survival)
library(penalized)
#> Welcome to penalized. For extended examples, see vignette("penalized").

library(mlr3)
library(distr6)
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'distr6'
#> The following object is masked from 'package:stats':
#> 
#>     qqplot
#> The following object is masked from 'package:base':
#> 
#>     truncate

library(mlr3verse)
library(mlr3proba)
library(mlr3learners)
library(mlr3pipelines)
library(mlr3extralearners)



data <- read.csv("C:/Users/Click_32235414/Documents/liver30.csv")

#convert data to tibble
tb <- as_tibble(data)

# delete variable with a lot of missing
tb <- subset(tb, select = -c(alcohol,smoking,micro_vesicular_steatosis_donor_liver_biopsy,
                             macro_vesicular_steatosis_donor_liver_biopsy,hdl_pre,hdl_post,phos_pre,
                             mg_pre,tg_pre,tg_post,ldh_pre,ldh_post,
                             ldl_pre,ldl_post,gamma_gt_pre,gamma_gt_post,t_chol_pre,t_chol_post,
                             micro_vesicular_steatosis_number_donor_liver_biopsy
                             ,reperfusion_syndrome,fibrosis_donor_liver_biopsy,
                             macro_vesicular_steatosis_number_donor_liver_biopsy))

tb <- subset(tb, select = -c(bun_pre,bun_post,pt_pre,pt_post))
tb<- tb[!(is.na(tb$time_to_death)), ]
attach(tb)
## Task Definition
tsk_s <- as_task_surv(tb, time = "time_to_death", event = "status", type = "right")
# imputes values based on histogram
imputer_hist = po("imputehist",
                  affect_columns = selector_name(c("meld_peld_score", "alk_pre", "alk_post","alb_pre", "alb_post"
                                                   ,"creatinine_pre","creatinine_post","na_pre","na_post"
                                                   ,"direct_billi_pre","direct_billi_post","total_billi_pre","total_billi_post"
                                                   ,"inr_pre","inr_post","phos_post","mg_post","ppt_pre","ptt_post","bmi"
                                                   ,"DeRitis_ratio_pre","DeRitis_ratio_post","cold_time","warm_time"
                                                   ,"graft_weight","max_Tacrolimus")))
# imputes values using the mod
imputer_mode = po("imputemode",
                  affect_columns = selector_name(c("biliary_anastomosis", "vasopressors","acute_kidney_disease_pm_history"
                                                   ,"diabetes_mellitus_pm_history","hypertension_pm_history","infections_pm_history"
                                                   ,"sbp_pm_history","cardiovascular_pm_history","previous_hospitalization_pm_history"
                                                   ,"Sirolimus")))

imputer_hist$train(list(tsk_s))[[1]]$missings()
#>                       time_to_death                              status 
#>                                   0                                   0 
#>                           Sirolimus     acute_kidney_disease_pm_history 
#>                                  19                                 107 
#>                                 age                 biliary_anastomosis 
#>                                   0                                 101 
#>           cardiovascular_pm_history        diabetes_mellitus_pm_history 
#>                                 107                                 107 
#>                              gender             hypertension_pm_history 
#>                                   0                                 107 
#>               infections_pm_history previous_hospitalization_pm_history 
#>                                 107                                 475 
#>                      sbp_pm_history                        vasopressors 
#>                                 107                                  37 
#>                  DeRitis_ratio_post                   DeRitis_ratio_pre 
#>                                   0                                   0 
#>                            alb_post                             alb_pre 
#>                                   0                                   0 
#>                            alk_post                             alk_pre 
#>                                   0                                   0 
#>                                 bmi                           cold_time 
#>                                   0                                   0 
#>                     creatinine_post                      creatinine_pre 
#>                                   0                                   0 
#>                   direct_billi_post                    direct_billi_pre 
#>                                   0                                   0 
#>                        graft_weight                            inr_post 
#>                                   0                                   0 
#>                             inr_pre                      max_Tacrolimus 
#>                                   0                                   0 
#>                     meld_peld_score                             mg_post 
#>                                   0                                   0 
#>                             na_post                              na_pre 
#>                                   0                                   0 
#>                           phos_post                             ppt_pre 
#>                                   0                                   0 
#>                            ptt_post                    total_billi_post 
#>                                   0                                   0 
#>                     total_billi_pre                           warm_time 
#>                                   0                                   0

imputer_mode$train(list(tsk_s))[[1]]$missings()
#>                       time_to_death                              status 
#>                                   0                                   0 
#>                  DeRitis_ratio_post                   DeRitis_ratio_pre 
#>                                 156                                 234 
#>                                 age                            alb_post 
#>                                   0                                  52 
#>                             alb_pre                            alk_post 
#>                                 258                                  64 
#>                             alk_pre                                 bmi 
#>                                 155                                 137 
#>                           cold_time                     creatinine_post 
#>                                 129                                  32 
#>                      creatinine_pre                   direct_billi_post 
#>                                 201                                  67 
#>                    direct_billi_pre                              gender 
#>                                 185                                   0 
#>                        graft_weight                            inr_post 
#>                                 118                                  79 
#>                             inr_pre                      max_Tacrolimus 
#>                                 210                                 481 
#>                     meld_peld_score                             mg_post 
#>                                 135                                 136 
#>                             na_post                              na_pre 
#>                                  33                                 206 
#>                           phos_post                             ppt_pre 
#>                                  91                                 463 
#>                            ptt_post                    total_billi_post 
#>                                 116                                  66 
#>                     total_billi_pre                           warm_time 
#>                                 163                                 128 
#>                           Sirolimus     acute_kidney_disease_pm_history 
#>                                   0                                   0 
#>                 biliary_anastomosis           cardiovascular_pm_history 
#>                                   0                                   0 
#>        diabetes_mellitus_pm_history             hypertension_pm_history 
#>                                   0                                   0 
#>               infections_pm_history previous_hospitalization_pm_history 
#>                                   0                                   0 
#>                      sbp_pm_history                        vasopressors 
#>                                   0                                   0

impute_graph = imputer_hist %>>% imputer_mode
surv_task = impute_graph$train(tsk_s)[[1]]

set.seed(42)
part = partition(surv_task, ratio = 0.8)

learner_penalized=lrn("surv.penalized", lambda1=25.8)

learner =
  ppl("crankcompositor",
      learner = learner_penalized,
      response = TRUE, method = "median", overwrite = FALSE) |>
  as_learner()

learner$train(surv_task, part$train)
#> # nonzero coefficients: 38# nonzero coefficients: 25          # nonzero coefficients: 27          # nonzero coefficients: 28          # nonzero coefficients: 27          # nonzero coefficients: 27          # nonzero coefficients: 26          # nonzero coefficients: 25          # nonzero coefficients: 25          # nonzero coefficients: 25          # nonzero coefficients: 25          # nonzero coefficients: 24          # nonzero coefficients: 24          # nonzero coefficients: 24          # nonzero coefficients: 24          # nonzero coefficients: 24          # nonzero coefficients: 25          # nonzero coefficients: 25          # nonzero coefficients: 24          # nonzero coefficients: 25          # nonzero coefficients: 25          # nonzero coefficients: 24          # nonzero coefficients: 24          # nonzero coefficients: 24          # nonzero coefficients: 24          # nonzero coefficients: 24          # nonzero coefficients: 24          # nonzero coefficients: 24          

learner::coef(learner$model)
#> Error in loadNamespace(x): there is no package called 'learner'

learner$selected_features()
#> Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos): attempt to apply non-function

Created on 2024-09-10 with reprex v2.1.0

I'm not familiar with this particular kind of model, but you can access the trained model through learner$model. On that, you can run whatever functions you would otherwise use to extract coefficients etc.

This is similar to the question here. You have to use:
penalized::coef(learner$model)

instead of
learner::coef(learner$model)

the $selected_features() function is WIP, see PR.
Also we now have a better pipeline to estimate the response (survival time) , check out the response composition pipeline

Thanks, John! Can you tell me when the 0.6.8 version of the 'mlr3proba' package will be released? The latest available version on GitHub is 0.6.6.

I don't know why you want to have the "official" release as the package sits only on GitHub - maybe because then it gets updated also on R-universe? Anyway! mlr3proba@0.6.8 is now released! Also please accept the answer if you found it satisfying :)
